# Script sort() ; getting "Service error: Spreadsheets"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm stuck on an error with what amounts to a "saved sort" run through a Google script (my first one). Here's the code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ 
    {name: "AllSort", functionName: "allSort"}
  ];
  ss.addMenu("Sort", menuEntries);
}

function allSort() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange(4,1,sheet.getMaxRows()-1,sheet.getMaxColumns()); 
  range.sort(2);
}
```

`onOpen()` works. `allSort()` is the problem. It works on `sheet3`, but not on `sheet1`. On `sheet1`, I get: `"Service error: Spreadsheets"`.

I've tested as many variations in the code as I can figure, and it always runs in `sheet3`, but not in `sheet1`.

`sheet1` had some `if/then` calcs, but I removed them and the problem persists. Beyond that, it has validated data fields and some conditional formatting, but nothing more exotic than that.

What I am missing?

UPDATE: I think it must have been too many header rows. There should only be one header row, I think.

Comment: Do you have frozen headers? Merged cells?

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be too many header rows. There should only be one header row, I think.